# Use a dropdown to add a style to D3 path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 map that I'm building. I want to change the map with a dropdown. The dropdown will determine a value, and based on that value, a style tied to the D3 map will change. How can I do this? I have tried to simplify my code as much as possible, but I don't know how to get it to work. In my example, if you choose the Bronx from the dropdown, it should turn the whole map red; otherwise it should be blue.

Thank you!

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ouuArH6mgwvcckNZDa1L?p=preview

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
    #boroughs {
      stroke: #aaa;
        stroke-width: 1px;
        fill: #ccc;
        width
    }
    </style>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <body>
        <select id="filter">
            <option>Select A Borough</option>
            <option value="Bronx">Bronx</option>
            <option value="Brooklyn">Brooklyn</option>
            <option value="Manhattan">Manhattan</option>
            <option value="Queens">Queens</option>  
            <option value="Staten_Island">Staten Island</option>
        </select>

    <script>
    var selection;

    d3.select('#filter')
            .on("change", function () {     
                var section = document.getElementById("filter");
                selection = section.options[section.selectedIndex].value;
    });

    console.log("selection:", selection);


    var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
        height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

    var container = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("id", "container")
        .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px");

      d3.json("nyc.json", function(error, nyb) {

      var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                        .center([-73.94, 40.70])
                        .scale(50000)
                        .translate([(width) / 2, (height)/2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection(projection);

        var map = container.append("svg")
            .attr("id", "boroughs")
            .style("width", width + "px")
        .style("height", height + "px")
            .selectAll(".state")
            .data(nyb.features)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d){ return d.properties.name; })
            .attr("fill", function(d){
              if (selection == "Bronx"){ return "#ff0000";}
              else { return "#0000ff";}
            })
            .attr("d", path);

        });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give classes to path such that they belong to that category on drop box:

```
var map = container.append("svg")
    .attr("id", "boroughs")
    .style("width", width + "px")
.style("height", height + "px")
    .selectAll(".state")
    .data(nyb.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    //this set the class
    .attr("class", function(d){ return "state " + d.properties.borough.replace(" ", "_"); })
```

Then on selection do:

```
d3.select('#filter')
        .on("change", function () {     

            var section = document.getElementById("filter");

            selection = section.options[section.selectedIndex].value;

            d3.selectAll(".state").style("fill", "blue");//reset all to blue


            d3.selectAll("."+selection.replace(" ", "_")).style("fill", "red"); //color the selected index
});
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XasWQPUchOIpwgvLbBdV?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a couple of things going through your plunker.

First, the class attribute isn't being set to anything on your paths. There is no `name` property on the data, but there is a `borough` property. Perhaps that is the one you want? If it is, you will need to do a bit of string manipulation on it to get rid of the spaces, as spaces in class names are not supported (I did this: `d.properties.borough.replace(/ /g, "_")` ).

Secondly, your change event handler doesn't actually do anything apart from setting the `selection` variable to the newly selected item. To actually update the chart, you will need to do something like this within the change event handler:

```
var section = document.getElementById("filter");
selection = section.options[section.selectedIndex].value;
d3.selectAll("." + selection)
   .attr("fill", "red");
```

Keep in mind that this code assumes that the `selection` variable matches the name of the class that has been set for each path in the SVG. You will also likely need to keep track of the currently selected borough, so that you can set it back to it's initial colour in the change event handler. I'll leave that to you to figure out.

Here is a working version: http://plnkr.co/sFrKwEIh0JmsaJGK36Kb?p=preview